# Launcher auto-hide not working Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: launcher, autohide

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04. I generally have the unity launcher in auto-hide mode. Problem starts if the desktop has been locked and then unlocked. Then the unity launcher does not disappear again.

Comment: Try this command in terminal : `setsid unity` & then try autohide!

Comment: @Jax-L Worked. But starting new session is not a permanent fix.

Comment: session problem? what happens? comment

Comment: Press `Alt+Ctrl+F3`,login with username & password & try this `dconf reset -f /org/compiz/` then `setsid unity` then `sudo reboot`

Comment: Interestingly the problem appears to be happening on if I lock the system using `Super+L` but does not happen if it is locked using `Alt+Ctrl+L`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Avoid holding down the <kbd>Super</kbd> button.

When locking the screen with <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> the <kbd>Super</kbd> key is normally held down before pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>. **But holding down <kbd>Super</kbd> is in itself a shortcut to get the Shortcut Help Screen up**. By using this to lock the computer, you make the sidebar reveal itself before it's "interrupted" by the screen locking. This is the reason why using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> does not produce the same effect: none of those keys have any effect on the sidebar, dash or the Help screen.

Either rapidly tap <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> simultaneously (**DO NOT HOLD DOWN `Super`**), use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> or find a way to remove the <kbd>Super</kbd> shortcuts for the Dash/Sidebar.

**EDIT**: Also found that **if your sidebar gets stuck, you can tap <kbd>Super</kbd> twice to get rid of it.**

Comment: So this is a bug right? The workaround you describe does work but it's very annoying :(  I looked around but didn't see a bug report. I'll try to file one later.

Comment: Yeah, I think this is a bug. I couldn't find a bug report for it either. It's a small annoyance with unity, but I don't think is high priority, so I kinda just left it.

Comment: Bug report is here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1334998

Comment: That double tapping Super trick is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 16):

You may have triggered the four-finger multi-touch command for revealing the launcher. Try swiping four fingers to the *left*.

Source: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch

Found completely by accident.

Comment: Yeah, I was getting *real* tired of restarting lightdm just to un-hide my launcher.

Comment: Double tapping *Super* didn't  do nothing on my ubuntu 16.10 while **swiping 4 fingers to the left worked perfectly**

Answer (score 3):

I solve it by changing the button with CCSM (CompizConfig Settings Manager):

1. If not already done, install `compizconfig-settings-manager` with the following command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
   ```
2. Open CCSM.
3. Select "Desktop" -> "Ubuntu Unity Plugin" -> "Launcher"
4. Turn the "*Hide Launcher*" from "`Never`" to "`Autohide`".

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please refrain from posting links directly in the answer, as they may change, and become dead. Also please explain your answer with more detail.

Answer (score 1):

This is considered a fixed bug and is resolved by Unity 7.2.2+14.04.20140714-0ubuntu1. The following command will bring you to the latest version. You may need to log out and back causing unity to restart to see the resolution.

```
sudo apt-get upgrade unity
```

Here is the official bug report:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1320438

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem ! you have to move mouse cursor to left top and press rightClick mouse + leftclick mouse and drag to center left . hope work it for you ;)